# unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 Name or service not known (0)

Tags: php, sockets

I have some strange problem here, socket connection to smtp.gmail.com fails when I try to execute script on site with `Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /var/www/test/test.php on line 2
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)` , but work fine if i run it in shell like `php test.php`, telnet works fine too and openssl connection as well, but web script just fail. I looked a lot of similar issues and didn't found an answer for that, any suggestions? 
I run nginx + php-fpm if, openssl enabled

UPD:
here is my test script:

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://smtp.gmail.com", 465, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "opened";
}
```

Comment: Try "smtp.gmail.com" instead of "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: Same error, and as far as i know stream_socket_client need to accept socket protocol

Comment: I saw an upd connection example at function doc (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php): `$fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 13, $errno, $errstr);`